# Is there any method to find a word in google sheet using flutter

Tags: flutter, google-sheets

I am trying to know if there is any method to get result if i type any letter in flutter textField like i want to call it in onChange method and i want 4 suggestion from that google sheet (like what it happens in google sheet when we Use ctrl+f in google sheet and type any letter it highlight the search result itself i want all row data of that cell )

Comment: https://medium.com/@nogadev/highlight-search-results-in-flutter-66f03974ddec. I found this blog hope this help to solve your issue.

Comment: no this is just highlighting the word of particular document stored in the app i want it from google sheet and entire row data from that sheet